# Auto Repeating titles and subtitles

Tags: beamer

In [Re-using the title of the previous Beamer slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66274/re-using-the-title-of-the-previous-beamer-slide/66331#66331), [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey) gave a solution for repeating `frametitle` and `framesubtitle` to the next frame.

However it does not work for `framesubtitle`. How should I modify the commands in order to make it work?

Example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66274/86}
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@checkframetitle{%
\begingroup
  \edef\temp{%
    \endgroup
    \noexpand\frametitle
    [\unexpanded\expandafter{\beamer@savedshortframetitle}]%
    {\unexpanded\expandafter{\beamer@savedframetitle}}%
  }
\temp
\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}

\long\def\beamer@@frametitle[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@ifempty{#2}{}{%
    \gdef\insertframetitle{{#2\ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount>0\relax{}\space\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle
continuation}\fi}}%
  \gdef\beamer@frametitle{#2}%
  \gdef\beamer@shortframetitle{#1}%
  \global\let\beamer@savedshortframetitle\beamer@shortframetitle
    \global\let\beamer@savedframetitle\beamer@frametitle
}%
}
  \global\let\beamer@savedshortframetitle\@empty
    \global\let\beamer@savedframetitle\@empty

\makeatother
% \end{add previous title and subtitle}

\title{Test Title}
\author{Pablo}
\date{September 23, 2013}
\institute{Teste Institute}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\frame{
  \frametitle{Title}
  \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item{Testing}
  \end{itemize}
}

\frame{
  \begin{itemize}
    \item{New item}
  \end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you clarify "does not work"?  I just tested it (albeit the code from http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65975/86 rather than in the question you linked to) and the framesubtitle seems to carry over from the last frame where a title was given.  Perhaps you could post an example where you aren't getting the behaviour that you expect, and say what you expected to see.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the response.
* sorry for the poor post, it is my first time in this forum.

1) I just edited the question adding an example code.

2) My problem is that in both examples from the links there is no \framsubtitle being used. I added a subtitle to the example you posted and it is not carried to the next slide.

3) In my example, I expect the "Subtitle" to be in both slides, however it just appear in the first one.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks Again!!

Comment: No problem about the post.  It's just hard to figure something out without code to experiment with.  As you see from my answer, I didn't even know about `\framesubtitle`, and my initial assumption was that it was the *short* title (ie the optional argument to `\frametitle`), hence my confusion.

Comment: I was very confused about what is the frame short title. I did some google and found some links. Please, correct me if I am wrong - it is a shortened version of the title for footers and should be used as: \frametitle[short title]{title}.

Comment: That's absolutely correct about the short title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I wrote the original code then I was completely unaware of the `\framesubtitle` command.  The original code can deal with a frame title and a short frame title, but not - as you say - the frame subtitle.  In actual fact, the subtitle is easier because there is a hook in the code that is called after the subtitle is set so we can hook into that and use it to save the subtitle into a global register.  Then it's just a few extra lines to the rest to ensure that the saved subtitle is restored at the start of the frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134308/86}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66274/86}
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@checkframetitle{%
\begingroup
  \edef\temp{%
    \endgroup
    \noexpand\frametitle
    [\unexpanded\expandafter{\beamer@savedshortframetitle}]%
    {\unexpanded\expandafter{\beamer@savedframetitle}}%
    \noexpand\framesubtitle
    {\unexpanded\expandafter{\beamer@savedframesubtitle}}%
  }
\temp
\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}

\long\def\beamer@@frametitle[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@ifempty{#2}{}{%
    \gdef\insertframetitle{{#2\ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount>0\relax{}\space\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle
continuation}\fi}}%
  \gdef\beamer@frametitle{#2}%
  \gdef\beamer@shortframetitle{#1}%
  \global\let\beamer@savedshortframetitle\beamer@shortframetitle
    \global\let\beamer@savedframetitle\beamer@frametitle
  }%
}
  \global\let\beamer@savedshortframetitle\@empty
    \global\let\beamer@savedframetitle\@empty
    \global\let\beamer@savedframesubtitle\@empty

\def\beamer@aftersubtitle{%
  \global\let\beamer@savedframesubtitle\insertframesubtitle
}



\makeatother
% \end{add previous title and subtitle}

\title{Test Title}
\author{Pablo}
\date{September 23, 2013}
\institute{Teste Institute}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\frame{
  \frametitle[Subtitle]{Title}
  \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item{Testing}
  \end{itemize}
}

\frame{
  \begin{itemize}
    \item{New item}
  \end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Working like a charm!! Thank you very much!!